# Is it possible to set higher z-index of the axis labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code labels of the axis get hidden behind the graph lines:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint=True)
C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

plt.plot(X,C)
plt.plot(X,S)

plt.xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi],
           [r'$-\pi$', r'$-\pi/2$', r'$0$', r'$+\pi/2$', r'$+\pi$'])

plt.yticks([-1, 0, +1],
           [r'$-1$', r'$0$', r'$+1$'])

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))

for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(14)
    label.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='None', alpha=0.75 ))

plt.show()
```

[image: cos/sin]

You can see that for instance `-pi` is hard to see. Is there a way to put axis labels up front?

Comment: Changing the tick label zorder doesn't seem to do anything for me, but if you set the zorder of the lines (in `plt.plot`) to something negative then they appear below the tick labels

Comment: Indeed, if I set `plt.plot(..., zorder=0)` it does the job. Any idea whether it's a bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: Feels like a bug but I don't know for sure

Comment: It's not a bug. It's the intended behaviour which can be changed if needed; see answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [rcParameter](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) `axes.axisbelow` which steers exactly this behaviour:

> `axes.axisbelow`: draw axis gridlines and ticks
>
> - below  patches (True);
> - above patches but below lines ('line');
> - or above all (False)

If you set

```
plt.rcParams["axes.axisbelow"] = False
```

at the top of the script, gridlines and tick(label)s are drawn on top of everything else. The result would then look like

[image]

Comment: What if one wants to keep the axes generally behind the data lines (colored lines) except for the axis tick labels (the text), which I would like to draw in front of everything? That is: z_axis < z_data < z_axis_tick_labels. My use-case is a polar-plot (round x-axis) with long tick labels. I can post a separate question if this requires a completely different approach.

Answer (score 6):

Although [Ernest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332569/4794) is very helpful, I find the `rcParams` interface a bit clunky. Luckily, you can set the `axisbelow` option directly on the axes with the [`set_axisbelow()` method](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axisbelow.html). Here's the patched version of your code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint=True)
C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

plt.plot(X,C)
plt.plot(X,S)

plt.xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi],
           [r'$-\pi$', r'$-\pi/2$', r'$0$', r'$+\pi/2$', r'$+\pi$'])

plt.yticks([-1, 0, +1],
           [r'$-1$', r'$0$', r'$+1$'])

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))

ax.set_axisbelow(False)  # <-- added

for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(14)
    label.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='None', alpha=0.75 ))

plt.show()
```

Now the plot looks like [Nicolas P. Rougier's tutorial](https://github.com/rougier/matplotlib-tutorial#devil-is-in-the-details) says it should:

[image: fixed plot with white background for tick labels]

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method. I tested it, it does the job.

Comment: This is weird, but `ax.set_axisbelow(False)` can not bring axis to the very front when there is any artist with `zorder` higher than 2.5.